# Can somone tell me what is the plugin used in the below snippet to get suggestions in VS code?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, plugins

[VS Code | Flutter Coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqEtU.png)

Can somone tell me what is the plugin used in the below snippet to get suggestions in VS code?

Comment: try `Awesome Flutter Snippets`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to  [Alexander](https://github.com/usernamehw) for this awesome extensions.
The name of the extension is **Error Lens**
[image: Error Lens]